# ERROR in : Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive NgClass

Tags: angular

```
ng build --prod
```

yields this error

```
ERROR in : Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive NgClass in /home/CAC_EAST/jhalliley/my-project/node_modules/@angular/common/common.d.ts.
```

I'm wondering if it's a version issue.  Here is the output of ng version:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.10.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.4.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.4.9
@angular/cdk                      5.2.5
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/json-schema              1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/package-update        0.3.2
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

I can't seem to get a build to succeed on ubuntu or redhat.  Ideas?

Comment: I think you've got [NgClass] where you should have [ngClass] in a component's template.

Comment: I'm using neither [NgClass] nor [ngClass] anywhere in my templates.  I do use {{ isFoo{} ? 'class1' : '' }} in my class values.

Comment: BTW: the same build does succeed on Windoze :(

Comment: That's unexpected. Nice!

Comment: But I don't use Windoze :P

Comment: This issue went away, but don't know why.  Perhaps a version change in some library made the difference.